# Pattern matching in Scala for String and Int

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

Why does pattern matching in Scala work for `String` and `AnyVal`s such as `Int`?

Usually we see things like `Case classes` or `Extractors`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extractors and case classes are used just for two of [13 kinds of patterns in Scala](http://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/08-pattern-matching.html#patterns), "Extractor patterns" and "Constructor patterns" respectively. You *can't* use `Int` or `String` in this kind of pattern (`case String(x)`). But you can use them in other kinds:

1. Typed patterns, as in `case x: String`. In that case there is nothing special about `String`, you can do the same with any class (but there is something special about `Int` and other primitives: `case x: Int` actually checks if the received object is a `java.lang.Integer` in most cases).
2. Literal patterns, as in `case 0` or `case ""`. Again, nothing special about strings, this works for all literals.

Answer (score 1):

`java.lang.String` is enriched with `scala.collection.immutable.StringOps` (http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/#scala.collection.immutable.StringOps) which mix `scala.collection.immutable.StringLike` (http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/#scala.collection.immutable.StringLike) in. There you can find complementary methods, like apply.

`String` is a bit special as well, you can convert it to list of `Char`s, and use `List` extractors then like `case List(a,b)` or `case x:xs` on a `String`, bearing in mind that `a` and `b` will be `Char`s; `x: Char` and `xs: List[Char]`

All primitive types have Rich* classes (e.g. `scala.runtime.RichBoolean`, `scala.runtime.RichByte`).

Value classes mechanics is used to enrich all of the above mentioned types (http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/value-classes.html). In compile time they have a wrapper type, like `RichBoolean` or `RichInt` but in runtime they are pure Boolean or Int types. In such way avoiding overhead of creating runtime objects.

Comment: "String is a bit special as well, since it's just a list of Chars, meaning that you can use List extractors like case List(a,b) or case x:xs on a String" Try it.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov you are right, you need to do `toList` before it'll work. I honestly thought it will work without extra efforts%). I will edit the answear.

Comment: Even then, converting a string to a `List[Char]` is pretty slow and the resulting list takes _a lot_ more memory than the `String`. _Much_ better to use `toSeq` (or implicit conversion to `Seq[Char]`), which will just create a small wrapper object, and use `Seq`-specific (but not `List`-specific) methods and matchers.

Answer (score 0):

```
val x: Any = 5
def f[T](v: T) = v match {
  case _: Int    => "Int"
  case _: String => "String"
  case _         => "Unknown"
}
```

Comment: I am asking why it works. String is an alias for java.lang.String, it's neither a case class not extractor, correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to define `unapply` in class to able to use that class in `switch/case`-style pattern matching. `unapply` is used to deconstruct object, so, if you want to match switch in `List`-style (`case x:xs`), you should use `unapply/unapplySeq`. Good example here are regexps, are they are constructed from strings -- `"something".r` (note `.r` in the end).